# Unable to auto refresh the excel SFDC connector for HPE

Tags: excel, vba, salesforce, connector, sfdc

I am trying to run a VBA or PS1 file that refreshes the excel connections. But the SFDC connector for HPE salesforce is not connecting.

```
$app = New-Object -comobject Excel.Application
$app.Visible = $True
$wb = $app.Workbooks.Open("C:\Sanjay Kumar\Reports\CaseAge30 - Raw Data.xlsx")
$wb.Name
$wb.Refresh
$wb.Save()
```

I ran this command but no luck.

Comment: $app = New-Object -comobject Excel.Application
$app.Visible = $True
$wb = $app.Workbooks.Open("C:\Sanjay Kumar\Reports\CaseAge30 - Raw Data.xlsx")
$wb.Name
$wb.Refresh
$wb.Save()